# Does wakanda mutex unlock when thread ends

Tags: multithreading, mutex, unlock, wakanda

Wak Server 10.187175
OSX 10.10.5

One of our threads uses Mutex.

Users complain that it sometimes seems to remain locked after thread execution completes.

Please verify that Mutex always unlocks when the thread either ends, or .unlock() is applied to the Mutex object.

If the thread crashes does Mutex unlock?